# How to get detailed exception?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I often do this in python exception:

```
try:
    <some process>
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

This is helping me when I want the script to keep going but still tell me that there is error. But, `print(e)` isn't as detail as if I let the exception raised. Is there any way to show the error more detail without raising the exception?

Comment: Try: [`traceback.print_exc()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_exc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to print traceback information.

As mentioned in the comments, you can use the [traceback](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/traceback.html#module-traceback) module's [print_exc](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_exc) function

```
try:
    1 / 0
except Exception:
    traceback.print_exc()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exes.py", line 10, in <module>
    1 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

If you are using the logging module, the [logging.exception](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.exception) function will automatically log the traceback as part of an ERROR level log message.

```
try:
    2 / 0 
except Exception:
    logging.exception('Something went wrong')

ERROR:root:Something went wrong
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exes.py", line 15, in <module>
    2 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

If you prefer to log the traceback at a different log level, you can pass `exc_info=True` to the log function to have the traceback logged.

```
try:
    3 / 0 
except Exception:
    logging.warning('Something went wrong.', exc_info=True)

WARNING:root:Something went wrong.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exes.py", line 20, in <module>
    3 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is really help me a lot